# Google OAuth consent screen not showing scope options

Tags: api, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am trying to set up the Google OAuth keys inside the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) with the right privileges for my project.

In a different project I am able to go to `Credentials/OAuth consent screen` and select from list of scopes. However, with my current project those options are missing. Both projects use the same set of Google APIs. I do not remember doing anything special with the one where the scope options are present, but apparently I am missing some vital settings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google makes changes to the developer console quite often.  They may have changed it since you set up your first project.

You can find the API scopes under the Library tab now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dalm To. All I can see in the Library tab are the APIs available to be added to my project. If I pick one of the APIs that was previously enabled I have to button (link) to "Manage" it. If I click it it just sends me to the Dashboard screen with the reports for the traffic, errors, etc. Am I still missing something?